# doPost function is stated as completed, yet does not modify the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a web app that writes to a spreadsheet in Google Sheets. My POST Request looks like this:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/",
  "query": {},
  "headers": {
    "x-forwarded-for": "",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
    "x-forwarded-port": "443",
    "host": "ad01b709cc5cc1208d9f1714f10aee4e.m.pipedream.net",
    "x-amzn-trace-id": "",
    "content-length": "4644",
    "user-agent": "WooCommerce/4.8.0 Hookshot (WordPress/5.6)",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "deflate, gzip",
    "referer": "",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-wc-webhook-source": "https://alansflowersandgifts.com/",
    "x-wc-webhook-topic": "order.created",
    "x-wc-webhook-resource": "order",
    "x-wc-webhook-event": "created",
    "x-wc-webhook-signature": "",
    "x-wc-webhook-id": "11",
    "x-wc-webhook-delivery-id": "29b01b0289ab8e69f2059"
  },
  "body": {
    "id": 10688,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "number": "4329",
    "order_key": "wc_order",
    "created_via": "checkout",
    "version": "4.8.0",
    "status": "processing",
    "currency": "USD",
    "date_created": "2021-01-07T13:10:43",
    "date_created_gmt": "2021-01-07T18:10:43",
    "date_modified": "2021-01-07T13:10:43",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2021-01-07T18:10:43",
    "discount_total": "0.00",
    "discount_tax": "0.00",
    "shipping_total": "11.85",
    "shipping_tax": "0.00",
    "cart_tax": "24.51",
    "total": "342.70",
    "total_tax": "24.51",
    "prices_include_tax": false,
    "customer_id": 1,
    "customer_ip_address": "184.56.201.139",
    "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36",
    "customer_note": "PLEASE DON'T DELIVER THIS!!!!!!!!!!",
    "billing": {
      "first_name": "D",
      "last_name": "Gadfly",
      "company": "Technical",
      "address_1": "25824 Wiki Lane",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "West Egg",
      "state": "NY",
      "postcode": "11102",
      "country": "US",
      "email": "rich@doe.com",
      "phone": "4405559136"
    },
    "shipping": {
      "first_name": "Funny",
      "last_name": "Name",
      "company": "Alan",
      "address_1": "12345 Pinehurst Ave",
      "address_2": "",
      "city": "New York",
      "state": "NY",
      "postcode": "90210",
      "country": "US"
    },
    "payment_method": "sb_test",
    "payment_method_title": "Order Test Gateway",
    "transaction_id": "",
    "date_paid": "2021-01-07T13:10:43",
    "date_paid_gmt": "2021-01-07T18:10:43",
    "cart_hash": "0f29dd8534d0e82756cb73",
    "meta_data": [
      {
        "id": 244949,
        "key": "_order_number",
        "value": "4329"
      },
      {
        "id": 244987,
        "key": "_shipping_phone_number",
        "value": "4555235551"
      },
      {
        "id": 244988,
        "key": "is_vat_exempt",
        "value": "no"
      },
      {
        "id": 244989,
        "key": "shipping_phone_number",
        "value": "5555432311"
      },
      {
        "id": 244990,
        "key": "card_message",
        "value": "To my dearest, my eternal, may you rest."
      },
      {
        "id": 244991,
        "key": "delivery_date",
        "value": "2/21"
      }
    ],
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": 1464,
        "name": "Deluxe Box Of Chocolates",
        "product_id": 1640,
        "variation_id": 0,
        "quantity": 8,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "151.60",
        "subtotal_tax": "12.13",
        "total": "151.60",
        "total_tax": "12.13",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "total": "12.128",
            "subtotal": "12.128"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 11638,
            "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "value": "",
            "display_key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "display_value": ""
          }
        ],
        "sku": "",
        "price": 18.95
      },
      {
        "id": 1465,
        "name": "Classic Box of Chocolates",
        "product_id": 1635,
        "variation_id": 0,
        "quantity": 4,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "55.80",
        "subtotal_tax": "4.46",
        "total": "55.80",
        "total_tax": "4.46",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "total": "4.464",
            "subtotal": "4.464"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 11639,
            "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "value": "",
            "display_key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "display_value": ""
          }
        ],
        "sku": "",
        "price": 13.95
      },
      {
        "id": 1466,
        "name": "Kalanchoe - Deluxe",
        "product_id": 733,
        "variation_id": 735,
        "quantity": 1,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "78.95",
        "subtotal_tax": "6.32",
        "total": "78.95",
        "total_tax": "6.32",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "total": "6.316",
            "subtotal": "6.316"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 11616,
            "key": "pa_please-select-an-option",
            "value": "deluxe",
            "display_key": "Please Select An Option...",
            "display_value": "Deluxe"
          },
          {
            "id": 11640,
            "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "value": "",
            "display_key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "display_value": ""
          }
        ],
        "sku": "XX-FP-KALAXXXX-00-XXX",
        "price": 78.95,
        "parent_name": "Kalanchoe"
      },
      {
        "id": 1467,
        "name": "Teddy Bear",
        "product_id": 1630,
        "variation_id": 0,
        "quantity": 1,
        "tax_class": "",
        "subtotal": "19.99",
        "subtotal_tax": "1.60",
        "total": "19.99",
        "total_tax": "1.60",
        "taxes": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "total": "1.5992",
            "subtotal": "1.5992"
          }
        ],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 11641,
            "key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "value": "",
            "display_key": "_WCPA_order_meta_data",
            "display_value": ""
          }
        ],
        "sku": "",
        "price": 19.99
      }
    ],
    "tax_lines": [
      {
        "id": 1469,
        "rate_code": "TAX-1",
        "rate_id": 1,
        "label": "Tax",
        "compound": false,
        "tax_total": "24.51",
        "shipping_tax_total": "0.00",
        "rate_percent": 8,
        "meta_data": []
      }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
      {
        "id": 1468,
        "method_title": "Flat rate",
        "method_id": "flat_rate",
        "instance_id": "1",
        "total": "11.85",
        "total_tax": "0.00",
        "taxes": [],
        "meta_data": [
          {
            "id": 11631,
            "key": "Items",
            "value": "Deluxe Box Of Chocolates &times; 8, Classic Box of Chocolates &times; 4, Kalanchoe - Deluxe &times; 1, Teddy Bear &times; 1",
            "display_key": "Items",
            "display_value": "Deluxe Box Of Chocolates &times; 8, Classic Box of Chocolates &times; 4, Kalanchoe - Deluxe &times; 1, Teddy Bear &times; 1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "fee_lines": [],
    "coupon_lines": [],
    "refunds": [],
    "currency_symbol": "$",
    "_links": {
    
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To format this data, and paste it into our Sheet, I wrote this script, which I deployed as a web app, with the sheet as a container.

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("request received");
}

//The MEAT
function doPost(e) {
  var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var order_number = myData.number;
  console.log(order_number);
  var order_created = myData.date_created.substring(5,6) + "/" +  myData.date_created.substring(8,9);
  var order_total = myData.total;
  console.log(order_total);
  var order_shipping = myData.shipping_total;
  var order_subtotal = parseFloat(order_total) - parseFloat(order_shipping) - parseFloat(myData.total_tax);
  console.log(order_subtotal);
  var delivery_state = myData.shipping.state;
  var recipient_name = myData.shipping.last_name + ", " + myData.shipping.first_name;
  console.log(recipient_name);
  var delivery_city = myData.shipping.city;
  var delivery_state = myData.shipping.state;
  var delivery_postcode;
  if (myData.shipping.country == "US") {
    delivery_postcode = "Z" + myData.shipping.postcode;
  }
  else {
    delivery_postcode = myData.shipping.postcode;
  }
  console.log(delivery_postcode);
  var status;
  if (delivery_state == "CT" || delivery_state == "DE" || delivery_state == "FL" || delivery_state == "GA" || delivery_state == "IN" || delivery_state == "KY" || delivery_state == "ME" || delivery_state == "MD" || delivery_state == "MA" || delivery_state == "MI" || delivery_state == "NH" || delivery_state == "NJ" || delivery_state == "NY" || delivery_state == "NC" || delivery_state == "OH" || delivery_state == "PA" || delivery_state == "RI" || delivery_state == "SC" || delivery_state == "TN" || delivery_state == "VA" || delivery_state == "WV" || delivery_state == "NF" || delivery_state == "PE" || delivery_state == "NS" || delivery_state == "NB" || delivery_state == "QC" || delivery_state == "ON" || delivery_state == "NU")
  {
    status = "EAS";
  } else if (delivery_state == "AL" || delivery_state == "AR" || delivery_state == "IL" || delivery_state == "IA" || delivery_state == "KS" || delivery_state == "LA" || delivery_state == "MN" || delivery_state == "MS" || delivery_state == "MO" || delivery_state == "NE" || delivery_state == "OK" || delivery_state == "TX" || delivery_state == "WI" || delivery_state == "MB" || delivery_state == "SK") 
  {
    status = "CEN";
  } else if (delivery_state == "CO" || delivery_state == "MT" || delivery_state == "NM" || delivery_state == "ND" || delivery_state == "SD" || delivery_state == "UT" || delivery_state == "WY" || delivery_state == "AB" || delivery_state == "NT")
  {
    status = "MOU";
  } else {
    status = "PAC";
  }
  console.log(status);
  var sheet;

  if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "01") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("January");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "02") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("February");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "03") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("March");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "04") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("April");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "05") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("May");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "06") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("June");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "07") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("July");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "08") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("August");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "09") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("September");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "10") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("October");
  } else if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "11") {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("November");
  } else {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("December");
  }

  sheet.appendRow([status, "AL", order_created, order_subtotal, order_shipping, order_total, " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " ", recipient_name, delivery_city, delivery_state, delivery_postcode]);
}
```

This code states that it completes fine, whenever it is run. However, nothing is added to my Sheet. Am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: So what's keeping you from debugging it and finding out why it's not working?

Comment: Just as a guess `if (order_created.substring(0,1) == "01") {` in google apps script and javascript returns from getMonth() method are zero to eleven so perhaps that's why sheet never got defiined.  But hey it's really your problem to debug your own code.

Comment: Altholugh I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, in your situation, when you redeploy the Web Apps as new version and test it again, what result will you obtain? By the way, in your script, `var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents])` is the value of `body` in above JSON data. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that should return just the body. Also, since it isn't returning any parsing errors, I'm assuming that it isn't having any issue with parsing.

Comment: Also, Cooper, I think the month thing should work, as earlier it is getting the month from a string that is in ISO8601 format (2021-01-07T...) which is why earlier I use a different substring to get the month. Even if the months didn't work, it would still write something to the spreadsheet, but it isn't. I've tried a lot of debugging, it just isn't writing to the sheet.

Comment: Are your logs showing anything when you make a POST request?